# TargetInvocationException when using uwp bluetooth APIs in .NET 5 winforms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uwp

The code works fine on `Windows 10`,
but I'm getting `TargetInvocationException` in `Windows 8.1` when using uwp bluetooth APIs in my `.NET 5` winforms app

[image]

inner exception is

```
Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
```

code:

```
private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher BTWatch = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
```

in my project I have added reference to "[UwpDesktop-Updated](https://github.com/Foda/uwp-desktop)" package & windows SDK 10.0.17763.132 is installed on my `Windows 8.1` machine.

[image]

Let me know how to fix this issue occurring on windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TargetInvocationException when using uwp bluetooth APIs in .NET 5 winforms app

I'm afraid you can't run it in Windows 8.1 system, please refer `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` document, the support lowest version is Build 10240, and it will not work in Windows 8.1 system.

Comment: so what are the possible options to make it work? I mean what if I use other versions of .net like 4.0?

Comment: It's more related with OS system. UWP api only works in windows 10 device.

Comment: I just want BLE to work in C# code on windows 8.1, not possible even with winforms?

Comment: please use pure desktop api or third part library to approach.

Comment: the issue is that I couldn't find any ble apis for desktop so I decided to implement the uwp ones. let me know if you have any reference to the desktop apis. thanks

Comment: Please refer this nuget  [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/32feet.NET)